# How to update style of commandLink after click?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, commandlink

I have JSF (RichFaces) project.
If condition false, `commandLink` has to be disabled. 
After the `action` is completed, `condition` is false, but `commandLink` is still active.

```
<a4j:commandLink action="..." styleClass="#{condition ? '' : 'disabled' }">
      <h:outputText  value="..."/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

What should I do to make it works?

Comment: Are you trying to disable the button? Giving it `class="disabled"` doesn't do that.

Comment: @Makhiel does it matter? I try to disable commadlink

Comment: Class is for changing appearance, if you're trying to make the button unclickable that's a different thing.

Comment: @Makhiel yes man, you give me good idea! I tried use commandButton with attribute onclick="this.disabled=true". And it works!